# Numeric integral of sin(x)/x

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, integral

I want to calcultate the definite integral with quadratures of sin(x)/x in python using scipy. With n = 256. It doesnt seem to work well:

```
 from scipy import integrate

 exact = integrate.quad(lambda x : (np.sin(x))/x, 0, 2*np.pi)[0]
 print("Exact value of integral:", exact)

 # Approx of sin(x)/x by Trapezoidal rule
 x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 257)
 f = lambda x : (np.sin(x))/x
 approximation = np.trapz(f(x), x)
 print ("Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2):", round(approximation, 5), 
   '+', round((2/256)**2, 5))
 print ("real error:", exact - approximation)

 # Approx of sin(x)/x by Simpsons 1/3 rule
 approximation = integrate.simps(f(x), x)
 print("Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4):", round(approximation, 9), 
   '+', round((2/256)**4, 9))
 print ("real error:", exact - approximation)

 plt.figure()
 plt.plot(x, f(x))
 plt.show()
```

The exact integral is calculated well, but I get an error with quadratures... What is wrong?

```
Exact value of integral: 1.4181515761326284
Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2): nan + 6e-05
real error: nan
Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4): nan + 4e-09
real error: nan
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least some issues in your code:

1. Your **linspace** starts from `0`, thus when you evaluate the function to integrate, at the beginning of the trapezoidal integral, you have: `sin(0)/0 = nan`. You should use a **numeric zero** instead of an **exact zero** (in the example below I used `1e-12`)
2. When you get the first `nan`, `nan + 1.0 = nan`: this means that in your code, when you are summing up the integral over the intervals, the first `nan` is messing up all of your results.
3. **for python 2 only**: The division `2/256` is a division between 2 integers and the result is `0`. Try with `2.0/256.0` instead (thanks @MaxU for pointing that out).

This is your code fixed (I'm running it in python2, this is what is installed in the pc I'm using now):

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

exact = integrate.quad(lambda x : (np.sin(x))/x, 0, 2*np.pi)[0]
print("Exact value of integral:", exact)

# Approx of sin(x)/x by Trapezoidal rule
x = np.linspace(1e-12, 2*np.pi, 257) # <- 0 has become a numeric 0
f = lambda x : (np.sin(x))/x
approximation = np.trapz(f(x), x)
print ("Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2):", round(approximation, 5), 
  '+', round((2.0/256.0)**2, 5))
print ("real error:", exact - approximation)

# Approx of sin(x)/x by Simpsons 1/3 rule
approximation = integrate.simps(f(x), x)
print("Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4):", round(approximation, 9), 
  '+', round((2/256)**4, 9))
print ("real error:", exact - approximation)
```

with its output:

```
('Exact value of integral:', 1.4181515761326284)
('Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2):', 1.41816, '+', 6e-05)
('real error:', -7.9895502944626884e-06)
('Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4):', 1.418151576, '+', 0.0)
('real error:', 2.7310242955991271e-10)
```

**Discalimer** The limit of `sin(x)/x -> 1 for x -> 0`, but due to floating rounding for `sin(1e-12)/1e-13 = 1`!

Answer (score 3):

You could make the function return 1 (the limit of sin(x)/x in 0) instead of `NaN` for x == 0. This way, you don't have to cheat and change the interval on which you integrate in order to exclude 0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

exact = integrate.quad(lambda x : (np.sin(x))/x, 0, 2*np.pi)[0]
print("Exact value of integral:", exact)


def f(x):
    out = np.sin(x) / x
    # For x == 0, we get nan. We replace it by the 
    # limit of sin(x)/x in 0
    out[np.isnan(out)] = 1
    return out

# Approx of sin(x)/x by Trapezoidal rule

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 257)

approximation = np.trapz(f(x), x)
print ("Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2):", round(approximation, 5), 
  '+', round((2/256)**2, 5))
print ("real error:", exact - approximation)
 # Approx of sin(x)/x by Simpsons 1/3 rule
approximation = integrate.simps(f(x), x)
print("Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4):", round(approximation, 9), 
  '+', round((2/256)**4, 9))
print ("real error:", exact - approximation)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Exact value of integral: 1.4181515761326284
Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2): 1.41816 + 6e-05
real error: -7.98955129322e-06
Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4): 1.418151576 + 4e-09
real error: 2.72103006793e-10
```

Answer (score 1):

NaN means "Not A Number". In your case is basicly infinity. When you create :

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 257)
```

You create an array with the value 0 in it, then you try to divide by x, and you can't divid by 0...

One solution is to use this :

```
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2*np.pi, 257)
```

Which give you this :

```
Exact value of integral: 1.4181515761326284
Estimated value of trapezoidal O(h^2): 1.31822 + 6e-05
real error: 0.099935104987
Estimated value of simpsons O(h^4): 1.318207115 + 4e-09
real error: 0.0999444614012
```

The closer you will be to zero the better the approximation will be !

Comment: I guess it would be better 0.0000000000001 then !

Comment: Haha, exactly, but even better is what Matteo just befor me, 1e-12, which is the smalest number possible before 0 !

Answer (score 0):

scipy.special.sici will return both the sine and cosine integrals.